# No video with supported format or MIME type found

Tags: php, html

My video won't play in my browser I've tried different file types and it didn't change anything I can enter where the file is uploaded on my computer like uploaded/video name and it will show but when I try to get it off my db with the  tags it says No video with supported format or MIME type found and when I try to get the video with the embed tag it says a plugin is needed to display this content
I am connected to my db at the top of this page too I just didn't include that here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Watch</title>
</head>

<body>
<video controls="controls" width="550" height="315">
<source src="<php $url ?>">
</video>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $url = $row['url'];
}

echo "Your are watching ".$name."<br />";
//echo "<embed src= '$url' width='560' height='315'></embed>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!";
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First check that your video format is compatible with your browser.
like, review ans : http://easyhtml5video.com/rq/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-error-with-ogg-video-converter-download-2Y.html

Comment: I've already checked for that and I also visited your link and converted a video to what that said and it still didn't work I've tried in Firefox and Chrome for this to work with different videos/types

Comment: What file type are you using?

Comment: I've tried mp4 mov and webm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced my commented out `embed` tags with `<video>` tags and it worked. I fixed this not long after I posted, but I'm leaving an answer for people who have this problem.